# Exported OBJ Models file location

Tags: export

Where do my models go when I export them as OBJ's? I tried searching everywhere for an answer but they all just say how to export, not where they go.

Comment: You have to choose the location you want to save the file in the export window when you are exporting.
People can't tell you where the file goes because it went to wherever you set it to.

Comment: To find the location of the ones you have saved, go through the steps that you did to save the previous ones but don't save it. Just look at the location it shows. I have to do the same thing when I download files from online.